# R GGplot labels in stacked barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(ab,aes(x=pk,y=Total,fill=Observation_Type)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack") + 
    theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),axis.text.y=element_blank()) +
    coord_flip() + 
    geom_text(stat="identity",aes(label=Total, color=Observation_Type))
```

The text(which is just the total number of observations) comes out looking very messy. For example Observation Type 1 is plotted first but in the labels Observation 2 shows up first.

Is it possible to:

- change the colors
- make the labels show up neatly in the correct place

Comment: Could you share few rows of your data.frame?

Answer (score 0):

We need to see your data.

Try changing as below:

```
+geom_text(stat="identity",aes(label=Total, color=Observation_Type),position=position_stack())
```